# How to remain the files of Apache IoTDB when the system is abnormally powered off?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I discovered a question related to Apache IoTDB. When the Cluster Version of IoTDB is abnormally powered off, some of the data files are always damaged. Sometimes are the resource files reported error, and sometimes are the tsfile reported error. What may the reason for this and how to fix it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.